# mySQL join two tables and display specific records in sorted order

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

**deposit**

```
accountNumber    balance    addDate
0000102          5000       21/01/2013
0000105          5500       21/01/2013
0010024          9800       21/01/2013
0000102          2500       22/01/2013
0000105          9000       22/01/2013
.......          ....       ../../....   //rest of the records
```

**withdrawal**

```
accountNumber    balance    addDate
0000102          2500       20/01/2013
0010024          5000       20/01/2013
0000105          1500       20/01/2013
.......          ....       ../../....  //rest of the records
```

Now, I need to display the results from these two tables as:

**details**

```
date          withdrawal   deposite
20/01/2013    2500
21/01/2013                 5000
22/01/2013                 2500
```

for the specific `accountNumber` = `0000102` and `order by` `addDate`.

I'm newbie to database.

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, with a minor change to JW's answer to alias the columns as requested in your comment:

```
SELECT addDate AS date, w as withdrawal, d as deposit
    FROM
        (
            SELECT  accountNumber, '' as w, balance as d, addDate FROM deposit
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  accountNumber, balance as w, '' as d, addDate FROM withdrawal
        ) s
    WHERE   accountNumber = '0000102'
    ORDER   BY date
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But this `query` printing `NULL` if there is no data. I need it to be empty. What can I do in that case?

Comment: The display of null values depends on the reporting tool you are using. Some display 'NULL', and some don't display anything at all (which is apparently what you want in this case). If you want an empty string then you can change null to '' (2 single quote marks) in the SQL statement - I will edit answer to show this.

Answer (score 2):

basically, you need to use `UNION ALL` here to keep duplicates on the result.

```
SELECT addDate AS date, balance
FROM
    (
        SELECT  accountNumber, balance, addDate FROM deposit
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  accountNumber, balance, addDate FROM withdrawal
    ) s
WHERE   accountNumber = '0000102'
ORDER   BY date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6959d/1)

Comment: Well, you get what you ask for! ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry: yes, thanks JW. I'm just looking forward that it works with me

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I did answer your question right? You edited your question which has a different requirement than the first one you have posted. You need to open for another question, not just updating it for another requirement. So if you have another requirement, you will update the question again and accept another answer right?

Comment: @JW. I'm really sorry for that. As I updated the question and the above answer is right for that context that's why I'd accepted that.